# vuex unknown action (or mutation) type

Tags: vuex, store, nuxt.js

I'm writing a simple code to set token in store in an Nuxt application. when I tried to call a mutation or action from my store, this error is logged in console: [vuex] unknown action type: setToken

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:()=> ({
        token: ''
    }),
    getters: {
        getToken: state => {
            return state.token;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setToken: (tokenStr) => {
            state.token = tokenStr;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        setToken: ({ commit }, tokenStr) => {
            commit('setToken', tokenStr);
        }
    }
})
```

This is a method trying to call the mutation:

```
methods:{
  setToken(){
    this.$store.dispatch('setToken','token1');
    this.token = this.$store.getters.token;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the 'classic' and now deprecated method of setting the vuex store in nuxt. You should set it up like this:

```
// store/index.js
export const state = () => ({
  token: ''
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_TOKEN (state, tokenStr) {
    state.token = tokenStr
}

export const actions = {
  setToken ({ commit }, tokenStr) {
    commit('SET_TOKEN', tokenStr)
  }
}

export const getters = {
  token: (state) => state.token
}
```

Nuxt will build the store for you from there. You can see it in the doc [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store).

Comment: the getter doesn't work without any error. I changed to log in console:  
token: (state) => {
        console.log('tokenStr');
        return state.token;
    }
nothing logged

Comment: A getter only gets when it's asked to get. In one of your pages or components try and use the getter, it should log then. Also ...mapGetters is a good way to use getters. Here's the link to [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) although the page seems to be currently offline.

Comment: well, absolutely I did this as you can see in my question:  this.token = this.$store.getters.token; (this.token is definded in data)

Comment: In your question you don't have 'state' as the first parameter in your mutation. Have you changed that?

Comment: tnx for your response; it worked, maybe i had a problem with mismatch names

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch actions in components with this.$store.dispatch('xxx'), or use the mapActions helper which maps component methods to store.dispatch calls (requires root store injection):
**Try Another Method For Dispatching An Action**

```
    import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
...mapActions([
  'increment', 
// map `this.increment()` to
```

`this.$store.dispatch('increment')`

```
  // `mapActions` also supports payloads:
  'incrementBy' // map `this.incrementBy(amount)` to `this.$store.dispatch('incrementBy', amount)`
]),
...mapActions({
  add: 'increment' // map `this.add()` to `this.$store.dispatch('increment')`
})
```

}
}